# WCF and Datetime parsing?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, datetime, datacontract

I got a WCF service(Webservice HTTP) that contains a service method, this method takes a datacontract containing a `DateTime?` (nullable).

There is now reports of exceptions when the client sends a string like this to this DateTime field

```
"2018-04-00T00:00:00"
```

I understand that this is not a correct datetime but accoding to the BizTalk user this is a webservice standard?

So how should I handle this with WCF?

Comment: `00` as a day or month?

Comment: 00 is the day (yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see how this is kind of grey area, but the fact is that the serializer cannot handle the data being sent. The serializer is your first line of defense against bad data in messages, and the only way (unless you have 500 lines of validating code) of catching all possible permutations of bad data. What if tomorrow they decide to send you a date like "2018-78-45T00:00:00"?

To me this means the burden of change is on the callers side. Full stop. The problem is not that they are sending data which is badly formatted, but that they are sending data which is just plain bad.

If they cannot provide correctly populated date values then returning an exception back to them with that information in is a completely reasonable solution.

Answer (score 1):

WCf uses [this DateTime xml schema](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime). And according to schema, the format seems valid, but since the third argument (00) represents the day and proper day parameters start from 01, it fails.

Comment: using your exception handling mechanism; this is an exception since data provided is not proper. Do you have an exception handling mechanism?

Comment: This exception is thrown before it enters the servicemethods and I only have exception handling within the servicemethods. It feels a bit strange that 00 is an valid value for the day, there is clearly no day that have the number 0 in a month? Are you sure this is correct? I could proably change the field type to string and then do a manual translation but if 00 is a valid value accoding to webservice standards, then one thinks that .NET should also handle it?

Comment: 00 is not a valid day, and that is the exact problem. I do not think you need to change anything, you need to decide what you are going to do if someone sends improper data to the web service. Are you going to ignore the data, are you going to send a response indicating that the data is not proper, are you going to log the exception...

Comment: Aha, as it is now, the service will throw an exception back to the sender as default faultcontract stating the problem. Its important that the messages is handled but the question is on what side(client or service) to make the change. If it is a .NET problem(can´t handle something that is standard) the I will have to handle it in the webservice in some way, but if it is in fact a faulted value then the client should be updated to send proper messages. So can you point out exactly where it states that 00 is an invalid value according to standard?

Comment: "For example, 2002-10-10T12:00:00-05:00 (noon on 10 October 2002, Central Daylight Savings Time as well as Eastern Standard Time in the U.S.) " : the day is 10 and it is stated as 10 October; so it means proper values start from 1.